# shallow rendering could not find component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

hi everyone I am testing my react application using jest. While testing a component I found that a test breaks unexpectedly throwing error as

```
Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.
```

test file

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import {AddLibraryItem} from '../../components/AddLibraryItem';
import libraryItems from '../fixtures/libraryItems';

let addLibraryItem, history, wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
    addLibraryItem = jest.fn();
    history = {push: jest.fn()};
    wrapper = shallow(<AddLibraryItem addLibraryItem={addLibraryItem} history={history}/>);

})

test('should execute on submit button successfully', () => {
    console.log(wrapper);
    wrapper.find('LibraryItemForm').prop('onSubmit')(libraryItems[0]);
    expect(addLibraryItem).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(libraryItems[0]);
    expect(history.push).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith("/");
});
```

Component

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import LibraryItemForm from './LibraryItemForm';
import {addLibraryItem} from '../actions/libraryA';

export class AddLibraryItem extends React.Component {
    onSubmit = (libraryItem) => {
        this.props.addLibraryItem(libraryItem);
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <LibraryItemForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addLibraryItem: (libraryItem) => dispatch(addLibraryItem(libraryItem))
    }
}

const ConnectedAddLibraryItem = connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(AddLibraryItem);
export default ConnectedAddLibraryItem;
```

The piece of test was earlier working very fine and test of 'LibraryItemForm' is also working fine and also rendering perfectly.
I am not getting what is wrong with it.
Is there any fix of it?

Comment: What's console.log(wrapper); returns on click?

Comment: result of console: console.log src/test/components/AddLibraryItem.test.js:20
      ShallowWrapper { length: 1 }

Comment: but snapshot is showing the existence of component

Comment: Could you please try to find by component not by `displayName`: `wrapper.find(LibraryItemForm)` ?

Comment: By component name it is working fine. But earlier when I was testing that same thing I didnt have to use component. and that is my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to `dive()`:

```
wrapper.find(LibraryItemForm).dive().prop('onSubmit')(libraryItems[0]);
```

[Enzyme documentation here.](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html)

Comment: LibraryItemForm with single quotes was working very fine before I made some changes to it. and 'wrapper.find(LibraryItemForm).prop('onSubmit')(libraryItems[0]);' is alo fine.

Comment: without using dive() the code works. But Why should we import component for test?